Can you remove the poles from $\frac{f'(x)}{f(x) - y}$ with $L^\infty_y L^1_x$ error?
I believe that the following below holds, which I need for some estimates. I have been struggling to prove it though!
Let $f \in C^1(\mathbb{R}; \mathbb{R})$ have finitely many critical points and be generally a rather nice function (for example a real power of a polynomial). I might need more assumptions but I could not nail it down yet. Let $y \in \mathbb{R}$ and $x_1 < \dots < x_n$ be all the solutions to $f(x) = y$. I claim that there exist $a_j(y), b \in \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$
\frac{f'(x)}{f(x) - y} = \frac{b}{1 + |x|} + \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{a_j(y)}{x - x_j} + R(y,x)
$$
where $\sup_{y \in \mathbb{R}, 1 \leq j \leq n} |a_j(y)| < \infty$ (actually trivial) and
$$
\sup_{y \in \mathbb{R}} \int_{\mathbb{R}} |R(y, x)| dx < \infty \,.
$$
The idea is simple and I can illustrate what is supposed to happend for the case where $y = 0$ and $\phi(x) = y$ has only one solution $x_1 = 0$.
Let's say we assume that both $\frac{x f'(x)}{f(x)}$ as well as $\frac{f'(\frac{1}{x})}{f(\frac{1}{x})}$ are differentiable at $0$ with value $0$. This means we can make the following Taylor expansions:
$$
\frac{x f'(x)}{f(x)} = a_1 + a_2 x + R_0(x) x \\
\frac{f'(\frac{1}{x})}{f(\frac{1}{x})} = 0 + b_1 x + b_2 x^2 + R_\infty\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) x^2
$$
which implies
$$
\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} - \frac{a_1}{x} = a_2 + R_0(x) \\
\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} - \frac{b_1}{x} = \frac{b_2}{x^2} + R_\infty(x) \frac{1}{x^2}
$$
where due to Taylor's theorem the remainder terms $R_0(x)$ and $R_\infty\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ are continuous at $0$ and $\infty$ respectively, and hence $R_0 \in C(B_1(0))$ and $R_\infty \in C(\mathbb{R} \setminus B_1(0))$. Basically, we can understand what happens near the pole and near infinity, and in both regimes cancel out the $\frac{1}{x}$ order.
I have of course tried to apply this technique to the general case but struggled with the following issues:

I need to estimate my remainder terms uniformly in $y$, and I have not been able to get a grip on that with the various forms.
I always have to deal with the function $\frac{(x - x_j) f'(x)}{f(x) - y}$. If $f$ is differentiable then the limit $x \rightarrow x_j$ exists, and it is $1$ if $f'(x_j) = 0$. More generally it seems to be the "order" of vanishing of the equation $f(x_j) - y = 0$.
Remark: I have posted another question about this function and I am about to answer it myself. We can understand its derivatives around $y$, and how exactly they blow up near a critical point.
When $x_0$ is near a critical point of $f$ the behavior of the above function becomes bad, related to the fact that two poles are merging into one.

I have a feeling that there should be some known theory regarding this. Removing the poles from your function should yield you something continuous, and removing the decay at infinity something integrable. Furthermore, why should this not work uniformly in $y$?
Lastly I would like to remark that I am trying to not only find the proof but also the lemma here. That is, if you find a counterexample to what I have exactly formulated, it indicates that further assumptions are needed but it might not fully answer my question.

What is $\phi$? Or do you mean “Let $y \in \mathbb{R}$ and $x_1 < \dots < x_n$ be all the solutions to $f(x) = y$” ?

Indeed, $\phi$ was my old notation, I forgot to replace it there.

Hmmm.... I wonder what you are going to do with $f(x)=x^2$ and small negative $y$. What you claim is, maybe, still feasible, but only if you allow complex $x_j$, not just real ones (or, equivalently, arbitrary rational functions of the corresponding degree). However, I'd rather wait for the confirmation that it will suffice for your purposes before saying more :-)

@fedja good point, I didn't consider that case. I think complex $x_j$ would still be fine for my case. My ultimate goal is to bound the oscillatory integral $\int e^{i z x} \frac{f'(x)}{f(x) - y} dy$ uniformly in $z, y$. The decomposition this question asks for would allow that.

The integral should be with respect to $dx$, not to $dy$ as you wrote, right?

@fedja yes, with respect to dx. The difficultx is the regime when $y$ is close to a critical point of $f$ and two poles merge. Right now I believe $x^4 - x^2$ might be a counterexample unfortunately but I can't prove it.

Let $f(x) = e^{x^2/2}$. Then this function has 1 critical point, at $0$. On the other hand for any $y < 0$, there are no solutions to $f(x) = y$. So your claim implies that there is some $b$ for which
$$
F_b(t) = \int \Big|\frac{x}{1 + t e^{-x^2/2}} - \frac{b}{1 + |x|}\Big| dx
$$
satisfies $\sup_{t > 0} F_b(t) < \infty$.
On the other hand,
$$
F_b(t) \geq \int_0^\infty \Big|\frac{x}{1 + t e^{-x^2/2}} - \frac{b}{1 + x}\Big| dx. 
$$
For $x_0$ sufficiently large, we have $x \geq x_0$ implies
$$
\frac{x}{1 + t e^{-x^2/2}} \geq \frac{2b}{1 + x}. 
$$
Thus,
$$
F_b(t) \geq \frac{1}{2} \int_{x_0}^\infty \frac{e^{x^2/2}}{e^{x^2/2} + t} x \, dx = \infty. 
$$
So--in fact--even though $f \in C^\infty$, your remainder is neither integrable nor uniformly bounded, regardless of the choice of $b$.

For your example $e^{x^2/2}$ we have $\frac{f'(1/x)}{f(1/x)} = \frac{1}{x}$, which is not continuous at zero. It was a bit hidden but I assumed this to say that the decay at infinity has the desired form. Well, you see the philosophy behind the question is less to find a counterexample any given attempted formulation of the lemma, but instead some formulation of the lemma for which it holds, if possible. Thank you for your reply though.
